# How can i add id and password (unique link) to survey link created with ibm spss data collection professional/author?

Tags: hyperlink, unique, spss, data-collection

I created a survey with ibm spss data collection professional/author. Survey link is like : http://survey.xxxyyy.com/mrIWeb/index.htm?I.Project=TestSurvey
I would like to add id and password to survey link for personalization.

I mean new link should be like: http://survey.xxxyyy.com/mrIWeb/index.htm?I.Project=TestSurvey&Id=xxxxxxxxx&PWD=xxxxxxxxx

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a little late for this answer, but this is quite easy to do.  During Project Activation, after authenticating to the server, select the `More>>` button in the Activate dialogue box, then on Project screen (the next screen to appear), at the bottom, select the checkbox `Use participants to specify who to interview` and click `Next`.  Then click on the `Participants` link in the Activate Project tree in the left-hand pane to expand it.  The activation wizard will then walk you through the steps to upload participants and turn on survey parameters to be passed via the URL.
[image]

The steps are basically:

1. Prepare a delimited file of participants to interview and save this file to your desktop.
2. Click the upload button after following the instructions above;
3. Click `Upload participants` and click the `Browse` button to search for and select the file you created in step 1;
4. Specify the database and table where you want the participants list to be uploaded;
5. Select which fields will contain the `ID` URL parameter and which will contain the `PWD` URL parameter;
6. Choose a script to control how participants will interact with your survey.  By default a dropdown list is provided with some common, vendor-provided scripts.  The most common one is the "Basic" script which only allows potential participants to access the survey by clicking on a link that contains the authentication parameters (or by typing them in to an authentication screen) and once they complete their questionnaire, they will not be allowed back into the survey;
7. Then proceed to activate the survey as you usually have.

Once you have completed these steps and you navigate to the URL of your survey, you will see that your are now prompted to enter an `ID` and `PWD` to gain access to the survey.  If you pass the `ID` and `PWD` as URL parameters, you will bypass this screen and instead, be automatically authenticated into the survey instrument.

See [here](https://support.unicomsi.com/manuals/intelligence/75/index.html#page/Desktop%2520User%2520Guides%2FInterviewScripting1.043.410.html%23ww1038886) for additional documentation from Unicom.